# Is it good practice to creating a generic subclass of UIViewController to manage all UI in iOS app?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift

I am writing an iOS application. In it I have created a file called UI.swift where I have implemented a class named `genericUIViewController`. I am implementing functions like `createView`, `createLabel`, `createTextField` etc to create UI elements. I am subclassing from this class in all other files where I am using these functions. Is this a good practice? The reason I am asking this is, I have to create same type of UI elements at many places. If this is not the way I should do, what is the that I should follow?

Comment: Are you only extending the functionality or are you also adding instance variables? If you are only extending the functionality, it may be more appropriate to use extension (roughly equivalent to category in Obj-C)

Comment: I am doing it like this. I am creating function like `createView`, then inside it I initialize a UIView and then customizing it according to the function `createView's` parameters and return the UIView instance.

Comment: Yes, but are you adding any instance variables to the class?

Comment: No, I am not adding instance variables to the class. I am doing everything inside the function that I create.

Comment: But, I may require to later for creating animations on objects. Not sure though. Like pressing a button would call a function which may animate something. This UIAction would have to be passed the instance also.

Comment: If the bulk of the job is to create UI elements, then perhaps just add factory methods in extensions to the UI classes themselves, or to your own generic "UI-factory" class. I don't see any particular need to subclass UIViewController here.

Answer (score 1):

These functions could then be static functions. Just put those in a separate class so that you don't need to create some sort of super base class. Maybe you could then also even use the 'Factory pattern' and you could even split this up in a ButtonFactory, LabelFactory, etc.. If you will create your objects using multiple steps per object (create object, configure object, ..), then You could use the 'Builder patter' If you want a description of those then you can have a look here: http://www.dofactory.com/net/design-patterns (sorry, samples are in C#)